# Converting to SSIS 2012 Project Deployment Model

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm converting our 2008 SSIS packages to 2012 and I want to use the project deployment model. I opened the SSIS packages in Visual Studio 2012 and had no issues converting them to 2012. I chose the simplest package and right-clicked and picked Convert to Package Deployment Model. I went through the wizard and checked "Remove configurations from all packages after conversion" on the Select Configurations screen. Again, I got no errors. I then built the package and sent the resulting files to our DBA for deployment. When he deploys, he tells me that he still sees the old project configurations (they're the two SSISConfig Connection Managers):

[image]

He says this shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The packages have those connection managers in them so they will show up on this screen. That doesn't mean they are being *used* though. In your two packages, delete the `SSISConfig` connection managers.

Comment: Do you mean delete the package configurations and the two connection managers before I convert them? Or delete them from the screen I show above after the conversion?

Comment: billinkc - if you put your comment as an answer, I'll upvote it and mark it as an answer. I removed the connection managers after conversion, then built the package and my DBA was able to deploy it and see it as he wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the packages *have* those connection managers in them, they will show up on this screen. That doesn't mean they are being **used** though. If they were only ever used for getting your configurations, they should be unused now but the wizard won't actually delete them.

In your two packages, delete the `SSISConfig` connection managers manually and the above screen should no longer report them.